# Displaying Copyright as caption on images

Tags: css, wordpress, image, elementor

I have a website where I want to display images which show the copyright symbol " ©"  on them.
Is it possible to change the symbol to show the image caption on hover?

I use Elementor Pro with Wordpress, I'm very new to this whole thing.

Currently, I have added the following CSS. It just displays the caption of the image on hover (bottom of the image). I'd like the hover to be triggered when the mouse overs over copyright symbol, but I don't know how to display that and then get the same result as the css below does.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

```css
 .widget-image-caption  {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 top:200;
 background:  linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 5%, black 100%);
 width: 100%;
  height:12%;


 text-align: center;
 font-size: 15px !important;
 color: white !important;
 display: grid;
 align-content: center;
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale(.95);
}



.widget-image-caption:after {
 content: "";
 font-size: 29px;
 font-style: italic;
color:#fffffff;
}


 .widget-image-caption:hover {
 opacity: .9;
 transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by changing the symbol? Are you currently displaying the symbol? If so please show us the code that does that. In any case put the code you have so far into your question.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the css i currently use to the question now,